# Code sequences for TLS on ARM

Tags: linux, arm, elf, abi, thread-local-storage

The [ELF Handling For Thread-Local Storage](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf) document gives assembly sequences for the various models (local exec/initial exec/general dynamic) for various architectures. But not ARM -- is there anywhere I can see such code sequences for ARM?  I'm working on a compiler and want to generate code that will operate properly with the platform linkers (both program and dynamic).

For clarity, let's assume an ARMv7 CPU and a pretty new kernel and glibc (say 3.13+ / 2.19+), but I'd also be interested in what has to change for older hw/sw if that's easy to explain.

Comment: I would do some disassembling (http://goo.gl/TPiQCX) then use those to google. https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2005-03/msg02375.html http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/publications/RFC-TLSDESC-ARM.txt http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/tls.h

Comment: Arguably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878698/what-are-the-real-elf-tls-abi-requirements-for-each-cpu-arch, but that one does not have a proper answer.

Comment: @unixsmurf  I think 'R's answer to his question and how to get the 'thread register' under ARM-Linux answer this question?

Comment: @artlessnoise: Not the ABI/ELF aspect.

Comment: @unixsmurf I dont' understand what you mean. Auslen's  [gcc changes](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2005-03/msg02375.html) are another piece.  The ELF stuff is a spec and is standard?  You use [.tlsdescseq *tls-variable*](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html) to add it to an ELF section in assembler (or a compiler does it).  A bunch of `R_ARM_TLS_` entries (but they are not code as per OP).  The loader must arrange the memory map as per the PDF.  You root this in the TLS register.  The trampoline jazz is if you want this lazy or not and is up to a tool suite.

Answer (score 4):

I don't exactly understand what you want.  However, the assembler sequences (for ARMv6+ and a capable kernel) are,

```
mrc p15, 0, rX, c13, c0, 2  @ get the user r/w register
```

This is called *TPIDRURW* in some ARM manuals.  Your TLS tables/structure must be parented from this value (probably a pointer).  Using the `mcr` is faster, but you can also call the helper (see below) if you don't set `HWCAP_TLS` in your ELF (which can be used on all ARM CPUs supported by Linux).

The intent of address 0xffff0fe8 **seems** to be that you can use those 4-bytes instead of using the above assembler directly with (`rX` == `r0`) as maybe it is different for some machine somewhere.

---

It is dependent on the CPU type.  There is a [helper in the vector page @0xffff0fe0 in entry-armv.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S?i#n1003); it is in the process/thread structure if the hardware doesn't support it.  Documentation is in [kernel_user_helpers.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/arm/kernel_user_helpers.txt#n75)

Usage example:

```
typedef void * (__kuser_get_tls_t)(void);
#define __kuser_get_tls (*(__kuser_get_tls_t *)0xffff0fe0)

void foo()
{
    void *tls = __kuser_get_tls();
    printf("TLS = %p\n", tls);
}
```

You do a syscall to set the TLS stuff.  `clone` is a way to setup a thread context.  The [thread_info](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/thread_info.h) holds all register for a thread; it may share an *mm* (memory management or process memory view) with other `task_struct`.  Ie, the thread_info has a `tp_value` for each created thread.

[Here is a dicussion](http://www.redhat.com/archives/phil-list/2003-May/msg00054.html) of the ARM implementation.  ELF/nptl/glibc and Linux kernel are all involved (and/or search terms to investigate more).  The syscall for `get_tls()` was probably too expensive and the current mainline has a vector page helper (mapped by all threads/processes).

Some glibc source, [tls-macros.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/arm/tls-macros.h;hb=HEAD), [tlsdesc.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/arm/tlsdesc.c;hb=HEAD), etc.  Most likely a full/concise answer will depend on the version of,

1. Your ARM CPU.
2. Your Linux kernel.
3. Your glibc.
4. Your compiler (and flags!).

Comment: The **TCB** in the PDF you reference is the `thread_info` structure under ARM-Linux.  Oh, and of course 'ld' (the loader) is involved. CP15 c13,c0 is used on ARMv6+.  There are three register.  User r/w, user read-only and privileged (kernel only); of course the kernel must be able to write all of them.  The ARM Linux only uses two (like the tp_values); besides these, the **other** assembler sequences are up to your imagination if you are implementing this on the ARM.  Ie, your question is not quite clear to me; do you want to re-use the *glibc* loader or write all user space yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was the mrc instruction that was most confusing me, I think. And I always forget the mess that is ARM CPU versions. I'll edit the question and then maybe you can edit the answer to suit.