# How do thread specific pointers work

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety, thread-local-storage

Recently I have discovered the magic of boost thread specific pointers. After some research on thread safety I would like to know how exactly boost thread specific pointers work.However, I can't seem to find this in the documentation. Can anyone provide some insight on this or some detailed documentation?

Comment: Most likely they are implemented using the host OS's thread-local-storage API:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage

Comment: There's a lot of useful information in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878698/what-are-the-real-elf-tls-abi-requirements-for-each-cpu-arch

Comment: See C++11 thread_local keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Boost [docs on thread local storage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html):

> `boost::thread_specific_ptr` provides a portable mechanism for thread-local storage that works on all compilers supported by **Boost.Thread**. Each instance of `boost::thread_specific_ptr` represents a pointer to an object (such as `errno`) where each thread must have a distinct value. The value for the current thread can be obtained using the `get()` member function, or by using the * and -> pointer deference operators. Initially the pointer has a value of NULL in each thread, but the value for the current thread can be set using the `reset()` member function.

And you can find the Boost [source here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/boost/thread/tss.hpp).

Comment: I get that. I was trying to find out what that implementation looks like under the hood.